# Let Magento Save CVV

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, security

I want Magento to save CVV. My system is internal and high security and we own our special hash to use  so there is no danger on this step. Can I know what SQL code to use and what is the file I need to edit?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what payment method you use to process credit card data. Magento offers the "Saved CC" payment method which stores all credit card data in your shop.

I would not recommend doing this as long as you know, what you're doing and what consequences it has.

> Important! Saving customer card data is discouraged unless absolutely
>   necessary. Even though the data is encrypted, being in possession of
>   the data increases your security risk. If you save customer credit
>   card numbers online, your store will be out of compliance with Payment
>   Card Industry (PCI) requirements.

See also:
[Let Magento Save CVV](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96835/let-magento-save-cvv)